# Extract unique elements from the input XSLT

Tags: xslt

For example the input is this:

```
<root>
<command name="comm1">aa</command>
<command name="comm2">bb</command>
<command name="comm3">cc</command>
<command name="comm3">dd</command>
<command name="comm2">ee</command>
<command name="comm1">ff</command>
<command name="comm5">gg</command>
</root>
```

The desired output is this:

```
<root>
<command name="comm1">aa</command>
<command name="comm2">bb</command>
<command name="comm3">cc</command>
<command name="comm5">gg</command>
</root>
```

You can see that at the output, we don't have repeating tags ,the text values are not important here.

Comment: Please state which XSLT processor will you be using.

Comment: Should the question be "Extract unique elements from the input XML using XSLT" instead of "Extract unique elements from the input XSLT"? See: http://dx.doi.org/10.14337/XMLLondon17.Gibson01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to XSLT 2.0, the easiest way to do this is probably to use an identity transformation (assuming you are *only* doing this task in this transform). You would need two templates:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="command[preceding-sibling::command[@name = current()/@name]]"/>
```

The first template copies the input to the output unchanged. The second template suppresses all `<command>` elements where there is already a `<command>` element with the same value for its `@name` attribute.

If you only have access to XSLT 1.0 we can replace the second template with something like:

```
<xsl:template match="command">
  <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::command[@name = current()/@name])">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>      
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

(there are other ways but that one is simple)

Comment: This is not a good method -see here why: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Yeah. I'm aware of that but, as I said, I was going for simple. A better solution would be keys but then you need to explain keys.

Comment: At least in XSLT 2.0, a better solution would be to use either `xsl:for-each-group` or `distinct-values()`. And Muenchian grouping has been explained many times before (e.g. in the article linked above), you only need to point to it.